# How to force composite indexes to appear in Google Cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Ok, see this picture in Google Cloud:

[image]

It said "**Below are the composite indexes for this application. These indexes are managed in your app's index configuration file.**"

And see this following code:

```
public static long getPropertyMaxIDStronglyConsistent(String entityName, String propertyName, Key parentKey){
            // Order alphabetically by property name:
            //Key parentKey=KeyFactory.createKey(parentEntityName, parentName);
            Query q = new Query(entityName, parentKey).setAncestor(parentKey)
                            .addSort(propertyName, SortDirection.DESCENDING);

            //List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
            List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q)
                            .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));        
            if(results.size()>0){
                Entity e=results.get(0);
                long maxID=(Long)e.getProperty(propertyName);


                return maxID;

            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }

    }
```

Suppose that we are running this **function1** `getPropertyMaxIDStronglyConsistent("EnglishClass", "ClassNo", KeyFactory.createKey("EnglishClassParent", "EnglishClassParentName"))`.

What I found out that, the **function1**  is not gonna work if the kind "**EnglishClass**" does not appear in **Indexes** Table with "**serving**" status.

I didn't know what I did but after I was struggling for a few hours then suddenly the Index "**EnglishClass**" appeared. When the "**EnglishClass**" appeared with "**serving**" status, the app can work as normal without any problem.

My questions are

**What are composite indexes?**

**Why didn't it appear immediately after running the function1?**

**What does "serving" status mean?**

**How to force composite indexes to appear in Google Cloud**?

Extra:
In the **datastore-indexes-auto.xml** I have

```
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="EnglishClass" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="ClassNo" direction="desc"/>

    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

But it still did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes for the App Engine datastore are described in [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig)  and [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes)(Java 7, but the principles are the same for Java 8).

1. A composite index is an index that comprises of more than one property of a model: for example an index that sorts a model by Model.name, then Model.creationDate.  Composite indexes are used by queries that need to access datastore records in the order described by the query.
2. Some indexes must be declared in the datastore-indexes.xml file - [see here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration)
3. Serving status means that the index is ready for use; when an index is first uploaded App Engine must build the index, and until the index is built queries that use the building index will throw an exception.  So it can be helpful to [update indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Updating_Indexes) before deploying the code that requires them.
4. Configure your app to [automatically configure indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_Using_automatic_index_configuration).

Comment: I added the Indexes manually & the "English Class" index did appear but it still did not work. Do not know why?

Comment: Show the manual change that you made to the indexes in your question so we can see if it matches the query.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. It still has not worked yet! do not know why?

Comment: Ok, I changed the config file a bit & it created a new Index. Now it works, but the question is. How to remove the old index? or can we just leave the old index there? If we leave it there, will it create any problem?

Comment: You can leave it there, unless you're processing lots (millions) of records it shouldn't so any harm.